# Удалить таблицу в Laravel используя базу данных Postgresql?

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-8

Таблица `sites`:

```
id|name             |
--|-----------------|
 1|https://test.ru/ |
 2|https://loop.com/|
```

Таблица `counterparties`:

```
id|client_id|
 1|    1    |
 2|    1    |
```

`Pivot-таблица` `сounterparty_sites`:

```
id|counterparty_id|site_id|
--|---------------|-------|
 1|      1        |   1   |
```

Миграция `pivot-таблицы`:

```php
<?php

  use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
  use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

  class CreateCounterpartySite extends Migration
  {
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
      Schema::create('counterparty_site', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('counterparty_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreignId('site_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
      });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
      Schema::dropIfExists('counterparty_sites');
    }
  }
```

При попытке удалить таблицу как с данными так и бе них приводит к ошибке:

> SQLSTATE[2BP01]: Dependent objects still exist: 7 ERROR:  cannot drop table sites because other objects depend on it
> DETAIL:  constraint counterparty_site_site_id_foreign on table counterparty_site depends on table sites
> HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too. (SQL: drop table if exists "sites")

Я так понимаю, что не срабатывает каскад потому, что это не удаление записей, а удаление таблицы(`sites`). Есть ли способ решить эту проблему, так чтобы сработал какскад?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Была похожая проблема.

```
$table->foreignId('counterparty_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
$table->foreignId('site_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
```

Эти строки мешают удалить таблицу, потому что другие имеют ссылку на неё. Сначала надо удалить ссылки, а потом можно будет таблицу.

Каскад предназначен немного для другого. Это если пользователь удаляет связанную запись, то удаляются и записи в связанных таблицах.

Подробнее читайте в документации [Laravel Dropping Foreign Keys](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#dropping-foreign-keys)

Comment: Нет, первичный ключ тут не причём, а вот ссылка на него мешает, в методе `down()` перед `Schema::dropIfExists` пропишите `$table->dropForeign('counterparty_id_foreign');    $table->dropForeign('site_id_foreign');`. Вы можете вообще не использовать constrained() и всё будет работать.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка не в миграциях и не ограничениях базы данных. Ошибка в именовании таблицы в методе `down()`. Таблица должна называться не `counterparty_sites`, а `counterparty_site`. А ошибка, которая в вопросе это уже следствие не удаления таблицы.

*Будте внимательны при именовании :)*